# Merging different Landsat scenes in Grass GIS?

Tags: grass-gis, merge, landsat

I am new to Grass GIS.

I have 17 scenes from Landsat8 covering an area. I have created color infrared images of bands 5,4,3 and now I want to merge all scenes into a mosaic, for further analysis. I can't seem to manage to do this, neither with `r.patch` or with `i.imagine.mosaic`.

Does anyone know another way for merging?

I tried also in QGIS, I exported from Grass as tiffs, loaded them into QGIS and used the merge command, but the images become grayscale and with some white corners overlaying.

---

I am attaching a screenshot of my result in QGIS, at the suggestion of @Joseph.

[image: merge fct]

Comment: Did you check http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/i.histo.match.html ?

Comment: Hei Markus, I did now, thanks. I don't think that's what I need, at this point, I can't put these rasters together. And I have to do this for 18 of them..

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in rasters (nor in QGIS for that matter) but have you tried manually setting the colours for the bands in QGIS?

*Layer Properties* > *Style* > Select "Multiband color" and configure the settings to your requirements.

[image: Raster properties]

Apologies for not providing a definitive answer.

Comment: Hei Joseph, thanks for the reply :) Yes, I am working with composite images, so I am after this step, and that's when I get funny results.

Comment: Could you please upload some screenshots of your results? Hopefully others will recognise the problem and provide you with a solution.